# Calculate distances between consecutive points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance, gps, spatial-outliers

I have a large dataset containing GPS points of various vehicles that are recorded every 10 seconds.

[image]

I have added a new `id` column to these GPS points in order to be able to connect them via the Points to Path tool by using the `id` field as order field.

```
car_id     LAT         LON         id
2891       4.899883    52.367300   1
2891       4.900583    52.366983   2
2891       4.901033    52.366900   3
2891       4.901100    52.366867   4
...        ...         ...         
2891       4.901572    52.367967   82
5892       4.901794    52.369302   83
5892       4.901749    52.369442   84
5892       4.901829    52.361554   85
```

The resulting GPS trajectory dataset contains outlying observations (the straight lines that  jump across large distances not along with the road network) which I want to remove. These route points are impossible because it would require acceleration/speed that these vehicles can not achieve.

[image]

In order to detect these unrealistically travelled distances, I would like to calculate the distance between each point to the next point in sequence (`id`) for each unique `car_id`. This mean that the distance to the end point of each `car_id` should be zero, since there is no subsequent recorded GPS point (see below). Eventually I want to set a maximum distance depending on how far it is possible for a vehicle to get in 10 seconds (150 meters?) and filter out distances above this threshold.

```
car_id     LAT         LON         id      DISTANCE
2891       4.899883    52.367300   1       13
2891       4.900583    52.366983   2       2
2891       4.901033    52.366900   3       14
2891       4.901100    52.366867   4       10
...        ...         ...         ...          
2891       4.901572    52.367967   82      0
5892       4.901794    52.369302   83      9
5892       4.901749    52.369442   84      12
5892       4.901829    52.361554   85      6
```

Is this the best way to get rid of these outliers, and achievable in QGIS?

Comment: Removing lines whose length is bigger than 150(for example) doesn't solve the problem?

Comment: The output of the 'Points to path' algorithm results in a single datafile where the lines are not individually identifiable.. What do you propose to get the length of each individual line?

Comment: You can use **Explode lines** tool. It gives you all individual lines.

Comment: On a side note, the lat and long have been swapped

Comment: Be careful when removing point/line: it works ok if the outliers are lonely. It fails if you have 2 or more consecutive ones. You may want to consider not only the "next" point but rather points outside of the max distance that the car can reach in 5 minutes (or else), then to remove groups of outliers. Don't forget to consider that the very first point could be the outlier

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz Ok I managed to get all the individual lines using the explode lines tool. But unfortunately QGIS keeps crashing when I try to calculate the length of the lines using the Field Calculator ($length). Any other ideas on how to get the length for each line?

Comment: Have you tried to create the lines using in the algorithm _Point to path_ with ID as _Order field_ and car_id as _Group Field_? This should help to avoid the creation of the extra lines and to have separated lines for each car.

Answer (score 3):

1. To keep your `id` attached to the points / vertices through line generation and other algorithms, you can add it as the M (or Z) dimension (algorithms *Set M value* / *Set Z value*) to your input GPS points layer.
   The `id` will then become a part of the geometry, and can be retrieved later using the *Extract M values* / *Extract Z values* algorithms.
2. Have you considered the *Extract vertices* algorithm?

   > This algorithm takes a line or polygon layer and generates a point
   >   layer with points representing the vertices in the input lines or
   >   polygons. The attributes associated to each point are the same ones
   >   associated to the line or polygon that the point belongs to.
   >   Additional fields are added to the point indicating the vertex index
   >   (beginning at 0), the vertex’s part and its index within the part (as
   >   well as its ring for polygons), distance along original geometry and
   >   bisector angle of vertex for original geometry.

   Unfortunately, you won't get the length of the segments, but you may be able to utilise the result, for instance by writing a script that does the subtractions.
3. The *Add geometry attributes* algorithm is an alternative to the field calculator for calculating length:

   > This algorithm computes geometric properties of the features in a
   >   vector layer. It generates a new vector layer with the same content as
   >   the input one, but with additional attributes in its attributes table,
   >   containing geometric measurements. Depending on the geometry type of
   >   the vector layer, the attributes added to the table will be different.